# Show UItableViewcell Selection

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I want to show `UITableViewCell` selection style "Gray" without selecting the `cell`. How can I achieve this? But I want to show it only for the first row of the `UITableView`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain this line... 
UITableViewCell selection style "Gray" without selecting the cell

Comment: Do you just want to get the gray look on your first tableViewCell?

Comment: yes,In first TableViewCell in first row.

Comment: I just want UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray style for first row.  Without selecting the cell.

Comment: creating a custom cell for the first cell, maybe? or using the section header, maybe? set the cell's background's colour to grey before it appears? there are so many options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)    
     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```

Put it in :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...
  if(indexPath.row == 0) {
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
     cell.selected = YES;
  }
  ...
}
```

Set the selectionStyle to Gray (this could be done in Interface Builder as well) and then set the cell as selected. Be sure to unselect the cell when it is reused.

Comment: I put this code, but its just showing the gray color and goes back to white automatically

Comment: sounds like you might be resetting either the selectionStyle or selected attribute somewhere. Could you post the code for your tableview delegate/datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

First Way:
Why not put a view at the top as you want and place a tableview at the bottom of that view .

Second Way:
Customize a separate cell for your first row and use an if else condition when you are putting these cells in the table view .